# Find out Text data in CSV File Numeric Columns in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am very new in powershell.
I am trying to validate my CSV file by finding out if there is any text value in my numeric fields. I can define with columns are  numeric.

This is my source data like this

```
ColA      ColB    ColC      ColD
23        23       ff       100
2.30E+01  34    2.40E+01    23
df        33      ss        df
34        35      36       37
```

I need output something like this (only text values if found in any column)

```
ColA         ColC       ColD
2.30E+01      ff        df
df           2.40E+01   
              ss
```

I have tried some code but not getting any results, get only some output like as under

```
System.Object[]


---------------                                                                                                                                                                      
                                                        xxx fff' ddd 3.54E+03 

                                                                                                ...
```

This is what I was trying

#

```
cls

function Is-Numeric ($Value) {
    return $Value -match "^[\d\.]+$"
}

$arrResult = @()
$arraycol = @()

$FileCol = @("ColA","ColB","ColC","ColD")

$dif_file_path = "C:\Users\$env:username\desktop\f2.csv"

#Importing CSVs

$dif_file = Import-Csv -Path $dif_file_path -Delimiter ","

############## Test Datatype (Is-Numeric)##########

 foreach($col in $FileCol)
  {
  foreach ($line in $dif_file) {

    $val = $line.$col

     $isnum = Is-Numeric($val)

    if ($isnum -eq $false) {
   $arrResult +=  $line.$col
   $arraycol += $col

    }
 }
 }
   [pscustomobject]@{$arraycol = "$arrResult"}| out-file "C:\Users\$env:username\Desktop\Errors1.csv" 
####################
```

can someone guide me right direction?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output order you want is quite different than the input CSV; you're tracking *bad text data* not by first occurrence, but by *column order*, which requires some extra steps.

test.csv file contents:

```
ColA,ColB,ColC,ColD
23,23,ff,100
2.30E+01,34,2.40E+01,23
df,33,ss,df
34,35,36,37
```

Sample code tested to meet your description:

```
$csvIn = Import-Csv "$PSScriptRoot\test.csv";

# create working data set with headers in same order as input file
$data  = [ordered]@{};
$csvIn[0].PSObject.Properties | foreach {
    $data.Add($_.Name, (New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList));
};

# add fields with text data
$csvIn | foreach {
    $_.PSObject.Properties | foreach {
        if ($_.Value -notmatch '^-?[\d\.]+$') {
            $null = $data[$_.Name].Add($_.Value);
        }
    }
}

$removes  = @(); # remove `good` columns with numeric data
$rowCount = 0;   # column with most bad values
$data.GetEnumerator() | foreach { 
    $badCount = $_.Value.Count;
    if ($badCount -eq 0) { $removes  += $_.Key; }
    if ($badCount -gt $rowCount) { $rowCount = $badCount; }
}
$removes | foreach { $data.Remove($_); }

0..($rowCount - 1) | foreach {
    $h = [ordered]@{};
    foreach ($key in $data.Keys) {
        $h.Add($key, $data[$key][$_]);
    }
    [PSCustomObject]$h;
} | 
Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path "$PSScriptRoot\text-data.csv";
```

output file contents:

```
"ColA","ColC","ColD"
"2.30E+01","ff","df"
"df","2.40E+01",
,"ss",
```

Comment: Thanks Kuujinbo, I am trying to understand your code. Only one issue here is that I need only few columns to test not the whole file. In this case ColA",ColB,"ColC","ColD are only subset of source file, that's why I was using array in my sample code.

Comment: Finally I managed to import only required columns and now this is working perfectly. Thanks alot for the help

Comment: in you code is not looking for any other special character like <,&$ etc. can you please modify the logic to look for all non-numeric characters ? Space before or after is not an issue.thanks

Comment: @Saim - updated answer to account for all non numeric, but allow the `-` character  for negative numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this,

```
function Is-Numeric ($Value) {
    return $Value -match "^[\d\.]+$"
}

$dif_file_path = "C:\Users\$env:username\desktop\f2.csv"

#Importing CSVs

$dif_file = Import-Csv -Path $dif_file_path -Delimiter ","

#$columns = $dif_file | Get-member -MemberType 'NoteProperty' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Name'
# Use this to specify certain columns
$columns = "ColB", "ColC", "ColD"

foreach($row in $dif_file) {
  foreach ($col in $columns) { 
    if ($col -in $columns) {
      if (!(Is-Numeric $row.$col)) { 
        $row.$col = "" 
      }
    }
  } 
} 

$dif_file | Export-Csv C:\temp\formatted.txt
```

1. Look up name of columns as you go
2. Look up values of each col in each row and if it is not numeric, change to ""
3. Exported updated file.

Comment: Thanks Jawad, it looks closer to my requirement. But I need to look for only specific columns in the file supposed to be Numeric , not all the columns because there are many text columns as well. To resolve this, in my sample code I am using an array of only those specific columns(colA, ColB, ColC, ColD)  to look for. Thanks.

Comment: @Saim You can use specific columns by updating the $columns variable. I think you already had that. If you update the variable $columns, rest of the script would work like you need.

Comment: Thank you Jawad for quick response. I tried with specific column in this code as you suggest. I am getting following error for each row like------------ Exception setting "ColA": "The property 'ColA' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set."
At line:19 char:7
+       $row.$col = ""
+       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionWhenSetting

Comment: @Saim Instead of using sets, simply use an array. See the code in the post where I defined the $columns. I tested and seems to work correctly now

Comment: Jawad, I am already using array as I mentioned in my code, but getting same error.When using file it's ok, but when using items from array it gives error. I am doing something wrong in using/creating array? thanks

Comment: And it looks the col name mentioned in array is not matching with the names in the csv file, despite same case/spelling.

Comment: @Saim use the if statement to check if the column (in the array) actually exists in the headers of the csv. Updated foreach loop should take care of it.

Comment: @Saim Your post is different from what I suggested. you need to update $row.$col like I showed you in my post to keep the same format. When you add data to $val or $arrResult, you are creating a new variable with new formatting. Did this not work?

Comment: it was producing complete file as output not only bad data.

Comment: @Saim Give the above a try again. I fixed the if condition to only check the columns in the $columns array

Comment: I found an issue with Is-Numeric function that it also excludes values with negative sign lik -15 or -5500 etc. Any better way to not to exclude negative sign values? thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think not displaying columns that have no data creates the challenge here. You can do the following:

```
$csv = Import-Csv "C:\Users\$env:username\desktop\f2.csv"
$finalprops = [collections.generic.list[string]]@()

$out = foreach ($line in $csv) {
    $props = $line.psobject.properties | Where {$_.Value -notmatch '^[\d\.]+$'} |
        Select-Object -Expand Name
    $props | Where {$_ -notin $finalprops} | Foreach-Object { $finalprops.add($_) }
    if ($props) {
        $line | Select $props
    }
$out | Select-Object ($finalprops | Sort)
```

Given the nature of `Format-Table` or tabular output, you only see the properties of the first object in the collection. So if object1 has `ColA` only, but object2 has `ColA` and `ColB`, you only see `ColA`.

Answer (score 0):

@Jawad, Finally I have tried

```
function Is-Numeric ($Value) {
    return $Value -match "^[\d\.]+$"
}
$arrResult = @()
$columns = "ColA","ColB","ColC","ColD"
$dif_file_path = "C:\Users\$env:username\desktop\f1.csv" 
$dif_file = Import-Csv -Path $dif_file_path -Delimiter "," |select  $columns
$columns = $dif_file | Get-member -MemberType 'NoteProperty' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Name'
foreach($row in $dif_file) {
  foreach ($col in $columns) { 
  $val = $row.$col
  $isnum = Is-Numeric($val)
       if ($isnum -eq $false) { 
        $arrResult += $col+ " " +$row.$col
      }}} 
 $arrResult | out-file "C:\Users\$env:username\desktop\Errordata.csv"
```

I get correct result in my out file, order is very ambiguous like

```
ColA ss
ColB 5.74E+03
ColA ss
ColC rrr
ColB 3.54E+03
ColD ss
ColB 8.31E+03
ColD cc
```

any idea to get proper format? thanks
Note: with your suggested code, I get complete source file with all data , not the specific error data.